# convert java list of map to spark dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a List in **java**

```
List<Map<String,Object>> list=new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("id", 1);
map.put("name","tom");
list.add(map);
```

I want convert it to spark Dataframe in **scala**,how to do it?

My real case is use mybatis instead of spark jdbc,because I  think spark do not use pool, I get data List with mybatis and convert it to spark Dataframe for calculation.

I know I can convert a scala Seq to Datafame:

```
 Seq((1)).toDF("id")
```

and also know how to convert a java `List<String>` to scala `Seq` 
But I do not know how to convert a java `List<Map<String,Object>>`

Answer (score -1):

List to Df:

DataFrame df = sqc.createDataset(data, Encoders.STRING()).toDF();

Comment: there is a compile error:`org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[String] does not take parameters`,here I assume sqc is SparkSession,data is the java list I give

Comment: private void start() {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Array to Dataset")
//                .master("local")
                .master("spark://10.0.100.81:7077")
                .getOrCreate();

        String[] l = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList(l);
        Dataset<String> df = spark.createDataset(data, Encoders.STRING());
        df.show();
    }

Comment: I am sorry I forget to say I want to convert it to scala   dataframe but not java  dataframe  .And I need the element of original java list is Map but not String,like `List<Map..>`.The previous compile error is in a scala file